# Webpack creating two bundles without entry point

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have the following source setup:

```
src
|__ client
|  |__ a.ts
|  |__ b.js
|
|__ common
|  |__ c.ts
|  |__ d.js
|
|__ server
|  |__ e.ts
|  |__ f.js
```

Both typescript and javascript files can exist in the sources. However, there is no entrypoint (no 'main file').

My goal is that I get two bundles:

- bundle_client.js
- bundle_server.js

Each bundle contains their appropriate code (typescript transpiled, and JS just passing through however the typescript transpiler can do that using `allowJs`), as well as both bundles containing the code from common.

This was easy with gulp, but I want to migrate to webpack and I can't figure it out.

This is the broken config I currently have:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require("glob");

const config = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
        }
    },
};

const clientConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    name: "client",
    //entry: glob.sync("./src/client/**/*.ts"),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: ['/src/client/**/*', '/src/common/**/*'],
                // test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle_client.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
    }
});

const serverConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    name: "server",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: '/src/server/**/*'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle_server.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
    }
});

module.exports = [
    clientConfig, serverConfig,
];
```

Googling around I found a couple of things that should help:

- Exporting multiple configs allows me to create separate bundles
- I can use blob to put all files as entry point

Comment: What *exactly* is broken here? As in, what happens when you run Webpack?

Comment: You are obliged to have an entry point. What you used to do with gulp not necessarily you'll do with webpack. Create 2 configs, one for each entry point, or one config with two different entrypoints and you are good to go.

Comment: @KirkLarkin The produced bundles are empty, they only contain index.js's content because I marked that as entrypoint, an empty file. I would expect the other files to be in the bundle as well.

Comment: @PlayMa256 What if I don't have any files that are static and could be used as an entry point? They are all dynamic and there is no "main file".

Comment: If you don't have, webpack is not the right tool for you, unfortunately, stick with gulp.

Comment: You can try create entry files, like this:
    const context = require.context('./client', true, /\.js$/);
    context.keys().forEach(context);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading up some more, I suddenly remembered you can have child `tsconfig.json` files in subdirectories of your project structure. Also it was made clear that webpack really, really wants an entry point, so I made a compromise, and found a quite elegant solution.

I added a `main.ts` to both client and server directories, as well as a `tsconfig.json`. The main (entry point), imports the rest (so webpack can create its dependency graph) and I have 3 `tsconfig.json` files.

`src/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/client/tsconfig.json",
    "src/server/tsconfig.json"
  ]
}
```

`src/client/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig",
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts",
    "../common/**/*.ts",
    "../../typings/natives_universal.d.ts",
    "../../typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the same for server's tsconfig.

And finally, this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const clientConfig = {
    entry: './src/client/main.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle_client.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
    }
};

const serverConfig = {
    entry: './src/server/main.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle_server.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
    }
};
module.exports = [
    clientConfig, serverConfig
];
```

This setup has several advantages:

1. Client has code completion (depending on editor) for client code and common code (and whatever external stuff is loaded), and same for server.
2. It creates two bundles in the `out` directory, one for client and one for server.
3. Only the necessary files are bundled, and following a normal workflow, client code and server code will never mix.

The only "downside" if you can call it that, is that I need an entry point, being main.ts which imports/executes other things throughout my code. Additionally, it is only softly enforced that client and server code doesn't get mixed. You can mix them, if you import them, as opposed to just not being able to locate the other's files when building.

But I am glad to make that compromise over having to violate webpack.